# Same partial view repeated in MVC3 (Razor)

Tags: partial-views, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a Person Model which contains the same fields (Name, ID, Phone, Email). I also have a Nomination Model that contains the Person Model 4x's for different types of people (a submitter, a submitee, a reference, and a manager).

I then created one Partial View that was strongly typed to the Person Model. My Submitter View then renders the Partial View 4x's (ex. @Html.Partial("_Person", Model.Manager)) for each of the 4 types of people.

However, when the form is submitted, the Partial View's all return Null data.

Now, I've been able to get this to work by strongly typing all the fields indepedently, but, it seems like I should be able to use a Partial View to not have to type out 4 different Name, ID, Phone, and Email fields.

Is there a way to do repeat a partial view multiple times like this?

Answer (score 1):

Is the form submitted in one shot? If this is the case then the model binding is failing because the names are the same, and mvc gets confused if you use the same names for the person model for one post back.

Let me know as I had this problem once as well, you might want to just pass the nomination model instead and you should find that it should work if in fact your model is failing because of several different objects having the same name.

Comment: Yes, it is being posted in one shot. And I believe your observation as to why it is failing is correct. But, I've never heard of a Nomination Model, and Google was little help w/ this term. What is that?

Comment: The nomination model is the model you said you have, which contains 4x person models lol (reread your message) ;), you should just pass that up to the action if your doing it in one shot then name confusion shouldn't occur :)

Comment: @Brandon Morales Let me know how it goes so we can make sure it all works for you.

Comment: Sorry, been away from this project for awhile, and that was awfully dumb of me to not catch what you meant by the nomination model. However, per your recommendation in 11/27, that doesn't work. I wound up not using a partial view and just rewriting the same thing over an over again for the 4 people involved.

Comment: you can send me the problem part of your project if you want, and i'll debug it and send it back, i'm certain its a simple solution.

Comment: I actually would like to take you up on that, I will send it next week. At this point, its more philosophical than anything. I already deployed the project to the client. But I just don't understand why I can't use partial views that way, and for future projects I would like to optimize my time. I will put together a simple example next week so I can send it.

Comment: Ok not a problem I look forward to receiving it and figuring this out :)

Comment: It would be great to see what came out of this theoretical project, my searches have come up empty so far. This problem seems like it should be pretty straight forward as the auto id functionality of ASP.net handled this sort of thing in the past :(